# how to bind json data to DHTMLxgrid?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, dhtmlx

I have return json from wcf service as a list and get json result in client.

How can I bind the json with dhtmlxgrid?How to load DHTMLXgrid with JSON data?

```
 myGrid.parse(data, "json");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find an article with the available formats of json data that can be loaded to the grid: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__data_formats.html#jsonformat